# Printing a Sine Wave to the Console

Tags: java, console, trigonometry

I'm working on a Java program that prints a sine wave to the console. This is what I've written so far:

```
int num = 7;
for (double y = 2; y >= 0; y-=0.2) {
  for (double x = 0; x <= num; x+=0.2) {
    if ( ((0.1+x) >= Math.asin((double)y-1)) && (((double)x-0.1) <= Math.asin((double)y-1)) )
      System.out.print('*');
    else
      System.out.print(' ');
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Essentially, this program treats each character on each line as a 0.2 x 0.2 area on a coordinate plane. If the sine function crosses this area, an asterisk is printed to the screen. Otherwise, a space is printed.
When run, this is printed to the console:

```
        *                          
     *                             
   *                               
  *                                
 *                                 
*
```

Can anybody tell me why my program stops after printing the first quarter of the wave?

Comment: This is because `asin` never gives you back a value outside -pi..pi. `sin`, on the other hand, is periodic, so you could try using it ([demo](http://ideone.com/YsCaOF)).

Comment: Ok! So I've been approaching this from the wrong angle. Thank you for the demo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only prints the first quarter of the sine wave is because of the indicated [range of `Math.asin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin-double-):

> Returns the arc sine of a value; the returned angle is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2.

Once you advance `x` past `Math.PI / 2`, then the `if` statement's condition will always be `false`.

You can take advantage of the fact that

sin(π - *x*) = sin(*x*)

and

sin(2π - *x*) = -sin(*x*)

by including more conditions.  (I've also removed the unnecessary casts to `double` for clarity.)

```
if ( (0.1+x >= Math.asin(y-1)) && (x-0.1 <= Math.asin(y-1)) ||
     (0.1+x >= Math.PI - Math.asin(y-1)) && (x-0.1 <= Math.PI - Math.asin(y-1))
     (2*Math.PI -(0.1 + x) <= -Math.asin(y-1)) && (2*Math.PI -(x-0.1) >= -Math.asin(y-1))  )
```

Output:

```
        *                          
     *     *                       
   *        *                      
  *           *                  * 
 *             *                *  
*               *              *   
                 *            *    
                  *          *     
                   *        *      
                    *      *       
                        *
```

Comment: This if-statement is definitely better than the one I wrote--it works. But, if I wanted to extend the graph even further, I would need to add even more conditions. There must be a more efficient way to extend the graph without repeatedly adding to the if-statement.

Comment: Yes, you can extend it beyond the current range.  Use the fact that sin(2π + _x_) = sin(_x_) and do your math (mod 2π).  Inside the loops, use `double x2pi = x % (2*Math.PI)`, then perform the `if` statement using `x2pi`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Whoops, skimmed the code a little too fast. This is wrong.**

Well, you set `num` to 7, then in your loop you take x from 0 to `num-1`, so you're only looping over 7 columns. Increase num and your graph should add additional columns. You'll have to increase the range of y values you loop over too, if you want the graph to extend to negative numbers.

However, your algorithm is extremely inefficient. You're calculating `asin(y-1)` twice for every square on your graph, when all you really need to do is calculate `sin(x)` once for every column. Why not just fill an array with precalculated sine values and then consult the array while drawing the graph? (I realize, of course, that on a modern computer it's fast enough to be practically irrelevant either way.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, `num`  = 7, but my loop increments by 0.2, so it should cover a little over one period of the wave. The array idea is clever, I think I may try to tackle this problem from that angle.

Comment: @coderPro97: If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the green checkmark. This lets other users see that the question has already been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: `num` has nothing to do with it I think. x is increased by 0.2, so there is much more than 7 loops... The correct answer is given in the comments by dasblinkenlight

Comment: @fishi: Ooh, you're right. Skimmed the code a little too fast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to arise from the condition of your if-statement, which almost always evaluates to `false`. You should check the calculus behind your conditional expression. I find increasing `num` does not really help here.

Maybe you should print another character instead of a whitespace by replacing `System.out.print(' ');` with `System.out.print('_');` for instance. This way you may be able to figure out why your program behaves that way. Reworking that algorithm of yours may also be helpful.

Comment: I think that the if-statement should be false 90% of the time. Otherwise, the function will be very indistinct. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help! Based on @dasblinkenlight's suggestion to use sin instead of asin, I found a very simple solution:

```
int num = 7;
for (double y = 1; y >= -1; y-=0.2) {
  for (double x = 0; x <= num; x+=0.2) {
    double sin = Math.sin(x);
    if ( (0.1+y) >= sin && (y-0.1) <= sin )
      System.out.print('*');
    else
      System.out.print(' ');
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

This prints this to the console:

```
      *****                        
    **     *                       
   *        **                     
  *           *                  **
 *             *                *  
*               *              *   
                 *            *    
                  *          *     
                   *        *      
                    **    **       
                      ****
```